# How to make SQL query in ActiveRecord using alias for the table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I want to make such a query for my `Services` ActiveRecord in Rails:

```
SELECT *
FROM "services" AS s
WHERE /* part using 's' alias */
```

Normally I'd write just `Service.where(/* where part */)`, but I need to set my alias.

I tried to run `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)`, but result of that is not recognized as `Service`.

How can I handle it?

Answer (score 6):

To use a table alias combine the `select` method with `from`:

```
Service.select("s.*").from("services s")
```

Which generates this SQL:

```
SELECT s.* FROM services s
```

And it returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which you can refine as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I found solution during writing this question.  `Service.find_by_sql(query)` works well in my case.